# Trailing zeros in string format in Stata

Tags: stata

I am trying to convert a **string** variable `A` in Stata to a **string** variable `B` such that each observation has a fixed length. For example the string variable A is

```
85
01
3
```

and I want to convert it to another string variable `B` with **trailing zeros** in order to get length 5 for each observations

```
85000
01000
30000
```

I know that in order to put **leading zeros** this code works
`gen B= string(real(A),"%05.0f")`. How should it be modified in order to get trailing zeros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your new variable is not the old one with a new format, but different values altogether. One way is:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
str2 A
85
01
3
end

list

*------ what you want -----

// desired length of string
local len = 5

// factor
gen xdif = 10 ^ (`len' - length(A))

// new values with new format
gen B0 = real(A) * xdif
gen B = string(B0,"%0`len'.0f")

list
```

You can make that a one-liner, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach that works equally well padding strings that contain non-numeric values.

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
str3 A
85
01
3
XYZ
"D F"
end

list

*------ what you want -----

// desired length of string
local len 5

// desired trailing character
local pad 0

// new values
gen B0 = "`pad'"*`len'
gen B1 = A+B0
generate str`len' B3 = B1

// new values in a single command
generate str`len' B = A+"`pad'"*`len'

list
```

Comment: William's last solution depends, although unproblematically, on Stata's truncating input. That is, given a storage type specification such as `str5` and a longer string, it's the string that gets truncated, not the specification that gets revised on the fly.

Comment: More crucially, in the generate statements for B1 and for B, I should have replaced `A` with `trim(A)`. The need for doing so can be demonstrated by adding `"X "` to the example input data. Apparently short input is treated differently than input with explicit trailing spaces, which confused me in creating my example.